# Is there a way to run JavaScript inside a Vimscript file?

Tags: javascript, python, vim

I am able to run Python 3 inside a Vim file.

```
if !has('python3')
        echo "Error: Python 3 required to execute script"
        finish
endif

function Main()
python3 << EOF
print('Hello, World!')
EOF
endfunction

call Main()
```

Using similar logic I tried to run JavaScript using NodeJS but to no avail.

```
" tried 'node' and 'nodejs' "
if !has('node')
        echo "Error: Node v10+ required to execute script"
        finish
endif

function Main()
node << EOF
console.log('Hello, World!')
EOF
endfunction

call Main()
```

Answer (score 1):

The ability to run Python 3 within vim scripts depends on the built-in Python interface described under `:help python`. Since there is no such thing for JavaScript/Node, what you want is impossible to achieve.

See `:help channel` for an alternative mechanism.